# jps displaying process that does not exist?

Tags: java, process

After send `kill -9` to all java processes. I can still saw their information using `jps`

```
sudo jps
14930 -- process information unavailable
6711 -- process information unavailable
15700 -- process information unavailable
23740 Jps
15135 -- process information unavailable
13743 -- process information unavailable
```

but if I check using `ps` command, there's no related information at all.

why is the case?